# Sockets, Cors Hostinger - Angular and PHP

Tags: php, angular, sockets, cors, hosting

I am making a system with PHP and Angular but when I upload it I get this error:
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://"rutahosting"/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OhIDRRm' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

In the same way this appears to me: **GET https://"rutahosting"/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OhIDRRm net::ERR_FAILED 404**

In Angular I have installed: ngx-socket-io and in the same way I have my file;
proxy.conf.json:

```
{
  "/socket.io": {
    "target": "https://"rutahosting"/Inventario/conteo.php",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  },
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://"rutahosting"/Inventario/conteo.php",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

And in Hostinger I have in my file .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://"rutahosting"/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c> 
 Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
 Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
 Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Accept, Accept-  Version,  Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, x-api-key, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token,Authorization"
 Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "*"
</IfModule>
```

Likewise, in my PHP file I have the corresponding headers:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); // Allow requests from any origin (Replace * with a specific domain to restrict it)
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"); // Allow specific HTTP methods
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"); // Allow specific headers
```

I don't know what file I need to generate or what configuration I have to have to do the CORS

I tried modifying the proxy.conf.json file and putting Headers in my .htaccess file, however I can't get it to work correctly, I looked for other alternatives, but I still don't have a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Your attempt to do it via the .htaccess might not have worked, because mod_headers is not available.

Comment: Doing it directly from the PHP script should work - unless you're in some kind of "headers already sent" scenario there. Do you have PHP error reporting turned up to the max, and checked the error logs?